# Aquire partial wakelock in a IntentService

Tags: android, wakelock, android-intentservice, android-wake-lock

My IntentService gets fired from 2 places, either by an Alarm or by the Activity and since the duration is related to the amount of data it needs do fetch from the web, from what I understood, I need to keep a partial wakelock.

Here's my implementation:

```
     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WakeLock");

    try {
         wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
         wakeLock.acquire(3600000); 

          ///other code here
    }
    catch{
    }
    finally{ 
         if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
             wakeLock.release();
         }
    }
```

My question is: will this work good enough? Will the `finally` make sure that the wakelock is released in any circumstances? From what I know `onHandleIntent` handles intent one after another, so there is no risk in having 2 intents/2 wakelocks in the same time.

Later edit:

The IntentService is called in 2 ways:

1. from my Activity, like

   `startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class).putExtra()..);`

2 from a triggered `Alarm` using a PendingIntent

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, someId, myServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Will the service have enough time to aquire wakelock when ran from the `Alarm`?

Comment: `wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);` this is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you need to keep wake-lock or not should not be related to the amount of work your `Service` does - theoretically, device can go to sleep even if the amount of work is small.

Wake-locks should be considered only if you absolutely must ensure that device can't sleep while the `Service` is running. Cases like this are very rare. Some examples:

- Alarm clock applications (need to wake you up even if the device is sleeping)
- Real time messaging applications (need to notify you about new messages even if the device is sleeping)

Most applications don't have such a strict timing requirements. For example, the following are NOT good reasons to use wake locks:

- Periodic synchronization of data with the server (should be delayed until device awakes)
- Displaying current user's location on map (can be obtained when device awakens; but wake-lock will be needed for applications that monitor user's entire route)

If you really need to ensure that the device doesn't sleep during `Service` execution, then you need to acquire a wake-lock (one of the several types). Let's assume that this is the case here.

You want to be able to start the "wakeful" `Service` from application's UI (`Activity`), and using `AlarmManager`.

**Starting from UI**

Since the device should be completely awake in order for the user to interact with UI, you can safely assume that if you start the `Service` in response to UI interaction it will have a chance to acquire a wake-lock (but do it as soon as the `Service` is started).

Your solution covers this case.

**Starting from `AlarmManager`**

Unfortunately, there is no guarantee (at least no documented guarantee) that when `AlarmManager` starts the `Service` it will hold a wake lock and allow the `Service` to acquire its own wake-lock. This means that the device can go to sleep after alarm fired, but before your `Service` had a chance to acquire the wake-lock.

This means that your solution will "break" in this case.

The only documented scheme in which `AlarmManager` will help you with wake-locks involves broadcasts:

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the
>   phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.
>   Once onReceive() returns, the Alarm Manager releases this wake lock.
>   This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your
>   onReceive() method completes. If your alarm receiver called
>   Context.startService(), it is possible that the phone will sleep
>   before the requested service is launched. To prevent this, your
>   BroadcastReceiver and Service will need to implement a separate wake
>   lock policy to ensure that the phone continues running until the
>   service becomes available.

This is where [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) comes in very handy.

Note that if you use this scheme, then there is no need to support a different one for "UI initiated" case - use the same approach in both cases.

You might also want to take a look at [this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) developed by @CommonsWare (I didn't use it myself though).

Comment: Using a broadcast receiver adds extra potential security related issues... Why on Android simple things are always hard to achieve? So I have no idea what use...

Comment: @Alin, "Why on Android simple things are always hard to achieve?" - the question we all ask (((