# Execution of ForegroundService is stopped even though WakeLock is acquired

Tags: android, service, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I´m trying to have a service that executes some code in a Handler at every second. While the phone is connected to the PC everythings running fine. However as soon as I start the service while not connected to the PC and I lock the phone, the periodic task just stops executing and executes all posted events when the app is opened again.

I´ve tried adding a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` in the `onCreate` of the Service but it doesn´t help at all.

**Service.java**

```
private PowerManager.Wakelock mWakeLock;
private Handler mHandler;
private Timer mTimer;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Notification notification = createNotification();
    startForeground(1, notification);

    // create and acquire the WakeLock
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "APP:LockName");
    mWakeLock.acquire();

    // create Handler for periodic code execution
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("PeriodicThread", THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();
    Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
    mHandler = new Handler(looper);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PeriodicTask(), 0, 1000);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimer.cancel();
    mWakeLock.release();
}


private class PeriodicTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(() -> { // periodic task here});
    }
}
```

I would expect the service to execute normally when the screen is locked, since the whole execution is protected by the `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. 
Or are WakeLocks Thread-specific and I need to acquire a lock for the newly created Thread?

Many Thanks for your help

### Edit 1:

I´ve tried adding the permission `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` to the app and even then the behavior is phone dependent. On a Samsung phone it works now as intended and the task is executed each second. on Huawei phone there´s no change and the periodic task is only executed when the app is opened again. 
Is there a way to at least secure the same behaviour on different phones?

Comment: Are you using Service or IntentService?

Comment: Service. That´s why I´m creating a new Thread for execution.

Comment: Use IntentService I think its better for your case.

Comment: and check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953458/aquire-partial-wakelock-in-a-intentservice

Comment: The problem is, that I also need binding between the active fragment and the service, which the IntentService doesn´t support. And as far as I know, shouldn´t an IntentService only handle short tasks and therefore not be running for a long time?

Comment: No service is for short tasks and it runs on main thread, but intent service is for long tasks. also you can communicate with your activity from intent service with broadcasts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intentservice

Comment: How is this a foreground service? You need to explicitly call `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)`? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background - wakelocks are ignored if the phone enters doze mode

Comment: @FaridForootan but how do I start the periodic task in the IntentService? If i create a TimerTask in the `onHandleIntent` it never executes because the IntentService stops itself.

@MarkKeen The service is started via `startForeground`. I´ve just excluded it for clarity. It should be added now.